# Multiple AlertViews - Remove the alertview that is behind another alertview

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I think this scenario should be weird one but i am stuck up with this.

I am having a view lets say View1, which will show one or more alertviews.Alerts are stacked one above the other if they are untouched.
The problem comes here.
If i click the top most alert ,it should take me to a complete new view lets say View2. And it does. Now i am getting the remaining alerts still shown in View2. I do not want this to happen . How can i auto dismiss the pending alerts created from View1 which are currently being shown in View2 ?

Any help or any idea is really appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite the answer to your question that you wanted, but...

Why do you have so many alerts? It sounds like you might be overusing them. Apple is quite clear in its Human Interface Guidelines about how you should use UIAlerts:

> Avoid creating unnecessary alerts.
>
> These alerts are usually unnecessary
>   if they:
>
> - Merely increase the visibility of some information, especially
>     information that is related to the
>     standard functioning of your
>     application.
>
> Instead, you should design an
>   eye-catching way to display the
>   information that harmonizes with your
>   app’s style.
>
> - Update users on tasks that are progressing normally.
>
> Instead, consider using a progress
>   view or an activity indicator to
>   provide progress-related feedback to
>   users (these methods of feedback are
>   described in “Progress View” and
>   “Activity Indicator”).
>
> - Ask for confirmation of user-initiated actions.
>
> To get confirmation for an action the
>   user initiated, even a potentially
>   risky action such as deleting a
>   contact, you should use an action
>   sheet.
>
> - Inform users of errors or problems about which they can do nothing.
>
> Although it might be necessary to use
>   an alert to tell users about a
>   critical problem they can’t fix, it’s
>   better to integrate such information
>   into the UI, if possible. For example,
>   instead of telling users every time a
>   server connection fails, display the
>   time of the last successful
>   connection.

If you're overusing alerts: don't. Then your original question may become moot.

Comment: I pretty much understand the HIG.. I am working on a chat application kinda thing... I handle chats for multiple users via alertview and thats where the problem comes. Anyway lot of thanks for your answer\

Comment: Ah OK, thanks. To me, it does sound like you're using a UIAlerts where you shouldn't be -- they're supposed to be for important stuff, rather than presenting general UI stuff.

Comment: And if you are overusing alerts, it's quite possible that Apple will reject your app. You really need to take their HIG stuff seriously.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
    UIAlertView *autoAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Auto-dismissed Alert" message:@"This alert will be dismissed in 5 seconds." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlert:) withObject:autoAlertView afterDelay:5];
    [autoAlertView show];
    [autoAlertView release];

-(void)dismissAlert:(UIAlertView *)alert {
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can dismiss the other UIAlertViews programmatically using:

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
```

You'll need to store a reference to them at creation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys! I wrote my own substitute for `UIAlertView`. I'm putting halftransparent `UIView` with `frame (0, 0, 320, 480)` to avoid user interaction while my custom alert still says "Please wait", and above this background view I'm putting this custom alert which is just basic `UIView` with `UIActivityIndicatorView` on it

P.S. Don't judge me for my english, i'm russian

Comment: How does this answer the question?